# UIActivityIndicatorView not centering on screen, specifically when UITableView is root view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, centering, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a weird issue where my `UIActivityIndicator` isnt centering in a NIB that has a root view of a `UITableView`.  My other views have a root view of `UIView` with a `UITableView` inside it and works fine.  The screenshot below shows the indicator isnt in the middle but a little further down.

```
UIActivityIndicatorView  *activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    CGRect frame = activity.frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width / 2 - frame.size.width / 2;
    frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height / 2 - frame.size.height / 2;
    activity.frame = frame;
    [self.view addSubview:activity];
    activity.tag = 1;
    [activity startAnimating];
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine for me sure this will help you

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activity=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
activity.center=CGPointMake(self.tableView.center.x, self.YourtableView.center.y-64);
  [self.YourtableView addSubview:activity ];
[activity startAnimating];
```

Comment: Why the minus -64?  That for the tabs or navigation bar?

Comment: This is the height of navigation + status bar

Comment: That worked, one question I assume this will work on all other devices too?